# Why is SMB Client not capable of using RSS although its enabled?

Tags: windows-10, networking, samba, smb

If I transfer a file through a 10G network, my client (W10) becomes laggy because it heavily maxes out one core:
[image]

Now I found [this explanation](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/archive/blogs/josebda/the-basics-of-smb-multichannel-a-feature-of-windows-server-2012-and-smb-3-0) how to use multiple cores:

> This typical configuration involves an SMB client and SMB Server
> configured with a single 10GbE NIC. Without SMB multichannel, if there
> is only one SMB session established, SMB uses a single TCP/IP
> connection, which naturally gets affinitized with a single CPU core.
>
> ...
>
> With SMB Multichannel, if the NIC is RSS-capable, SMB will create
> multiple TCP/IP connections for that single session, avoiding a
> potential bottleneck on a single CPU core when lots of small IOs are
> required.
> [image]

I enabled Multichannel on my unraid server through smb.conf as follows and restarted the smb service:

```
server multi channel support = yes
```

After that the powershell command `Get-SmbMultichannelConnection` on the client returns a result (before it was empty):

```
Server Name Selected Client IP      Server IP     Client Interface Index Server Interface Index Client RSS Capable Client RDMA Capable
----------- -------- ---------      ---------     ---------------------- ---------------------- ------------------ -------------------
THOTH       True     192.168.178.21 192.168.178.9 11                     13                     False              False
```

But as you can see **Client RSS Capable** is **False**.

I checked my adapter and Receive Side Scaling (RSS) is enabled:

[image]

`Get-SmbClientNetworkInterface` confirms it:

```
Interface Index RSS Capable RDMA Capable Speed   IpAddresses      Friendly Name
--------------- ----------- ------------ -----   -----------      -------------
11              True        False        10 Gbps {192.168.178.21} Ethernet 3
```

`Get-NetAdapterRss` returns "MaxProcessors = 4":

```
Name                                            : Ethernet 3
InterfaceDescription                            : Aquantia AQtion 10Gbit Network Adapter
Enabled                                         : True
NumberOfReceiveQueues                           : 4
Profile                                         : NUMAStatic
BaseProcessor: [Group:Number]                   : 0:0
MaxProcessor: [Group:Number]                    : 0:3
MaxProcessors                                   : 4
RssProcessorArray: [Group:Number/NUMA Distance] : 0:0/0  0:1/0  0:2/0  0:3/0
IndirectionTable: [Group:Number]                : 0:0   0:1     0:2     0:3     0:0     0:1     0:2     0:3
                                                  0:0   0:1     0:2     0:3     0:0     0:1     0:2     0:3
                                                  0:0   0:1     0:2     0:3     0:0     0:1     0:2     0:3
                                                  0:0   0:1     0:2     0:3     0:0     0:1     0:2     0:3
                                                  0:0   0:1     0:2     0:3     0:0     0:1     0:2     0:3
                                                  0:0   0:1     0:2     0:3     0:0     0:1     0:2     0:3
                                                  0:0   0:1     0:2     0:3     0:0     0:1     0:2     0:3
                                                  0:0   0:1     0:2     0:3     0:0     0:1     0:2     0:3
```

`Get-SmbClientConfiguration` returns "EnableMultiChannel = True":

```
ConnectionCountPerRssNetworkInterface : 4
DirectoryCacheEntriesMax              : 16
DirectoryCacheEntrySizeMax            : 65536
DirectoryCacheLifetime                : 10
DormantFileLimit                      : 1023
EnableBandwidthThrottling             : True
EnableByteRangeLockingOnReadOnlyFiles : True
EnableInsecureGuestLogons             : True
EnableLargeMtu                        : True
EnableLoadBalanceScaleOut             : True
EnableMultiChannel                    : True
EnableSecuritySignature               : True
ExtendedSessionTimeout                : 1000
FileInfoCacheEntriesMax               : 64
FileInfoCacheLifetime                 : 10
FileNotFoundCacheEntriesMax           : 128
FileNotFoundCacheLifetime             : 5
KeepConn                              : 600
MaxCmds                               : 50
MaximumConnectionCountPerServer       : 32
OplocksDisabled                       : False
RequireSecuritySignature              : False
SessionTimeout                        : 60
UseOpportunisticLocking               : True
WindowSizeThreshold                   : 8
```

So what could be the reason why my client is not capable to use RSS?

**Update1**

To exclude server dependencies I used [this documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/performance_tuning_guide/network-rss) to check if my servers network card has RSS capability:

```
egrep 'CPU|eth0' /proc/interrupts
            CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       
 129:   29144060          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI 524288-edge      eth0
 131:          0   25511547          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI 524289-edge      eth0
 132:          0          0   40776464          0  IR-PCI-MSI 524290-edge      eth0
 134:          0          0          0   17121614  IR-PCI-MSI 524291-edge      eth0

ethtool -x eth0
RX flow hash indirection table for eth0 with 4 RX ring(s):
    0:      0     1     2     3     0     1     2     3
    8:      0     1     2     3     0     1     2     3
   16:      0     1     2     3     0     1     2     3
   24:      0     1     2     3     0     1     2     3
   32:      0     1     2     3     0     1     2     3
   40:      0     1     2     3     0     1     2     3
   48:      0     1     2     3     0     1     2     3
   56:      0     1     2     3     0     1     2     3
RSS hash key:
1e:ad:71:87:65:fc:26:7d:0d:45:67:74:cd:06:1a:18:b6:c1:f0:c7:bb:18:be:f8:19:13:4b:a9:d0:3e:fe:70:25:03:ab:50:6a:8b:82:0c
RSS hash function:
    toeplitz: on
    xor: off
    crc32: off
```

Comment: Looking at the the individual CPU graphs is not useful as Windows moves periodically tasks from one core to another. Therefore you should better use the combined/total CPU usage graph which shows 55% hence two cores fully utilized.

Comment: Useful or not, without RSS it's not possible to enable multithreading and this is my target.

Comment: I still don't see the point in your question. You have a 10GBit connection and 1.06GB/sec transfer speed. This is not perfect but also not bad for a 10GBit connection. RSS is enabled and your system reports that up to 4 connections are used. That the CPU utilization is not that distributed as shown in the sample graphs is IMHO not a problem and indicates nothing. And that the system feels "laggy" is most likely not a CPU problem because you have 4 cores, 2 of them nearly unused. Have you checked other potential reasons impacting the system speed such as SSD temperature?

Comment: Isn't it only a config value and not the real usage? I mean `Get-SmbMultichannelConnection` returns `false` for `Client RSS Capable` and the documentation says `true` is the requirement. Maybe interesting as well: Now only the 3rd core is at maximum while the transfer is running and the lags are gone. I would say that "explorer.exe" runs at the 1st Core and now its not influenced anymore. Regarding temps: 970 Pro is between 40 and 60 degree whilte testing and has no visible throttling (reviews say it throttles at 80 degree to 1.5 GB/s). Server does not throttle, too (file comes from RAM).

Comment: Have you enabled to use multiple Explorer processes? https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/125919-enable-disable-launch-folder-windows-separate-process-windows.html This may have a positive effect on the responsiveness of the desktop.

Comment: Nope, did that (yesterday), but does not influence the lags. Today it was laggy again while transfering and this time it used the 1st Core again. ^^

Comment: @Robert I solved the issue :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve the issue. `Client RSS Capable` was `False` because the Server did not provide its RSS capability. To enable RSS I needed to add this to my smb.conf (or `speed=1000000000` for 1G network adapter):

```
server multi channel support = yes
interfaces = "10.10.10.10;capability=RSS,speed=10000000000"
```

Its really [bad explained in the SMB documentation](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html#INTERFACES) and finally the syntax and example are wrong:

```
In order to support SMB3 multi-channel configurations, smbd understands some extra data that can be appended after the actual interface with this extended syntax:

interface[;key1=value1[,key2=value2[...]]]

Known keys are speed, capability, and if_index. Speed is specified in bits per second. Known capabilities are RSS and RDMA.

...

Example: interfaces = eth0 192.168.2.10/24 192.168.3.10/255.255.255.0
```

The syntax must contain the ip-address of the adapter (a name like "eth0" does not work!) and quotation marks are a must. [This samba bug](https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14142) gave me the hint for that and [this blog post](https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14142) finally confirmed it:

> In my case the interface value had to be an IP address. Attempting to
> specify an interface name (e.g. lagg0 or vlan101) did not work and
> caused the SMB daemon not to start because it couldn’t find any
> working interfaces. This is contrary to what the documentation says.

And this is the result (and the lags are completely gone):
[image]

More results and the full story can be found [here](https://forums.unraid.net/topic/69103-smb-multichannel-still-experimental/).

Comment: Thank you very much for this extensive description of the problem and solution. This got me 99% of the way. I also had to enable RSS system-wide on my Windows machine, probably because I had disabled it in the past for some reason: `netsh interface tcp set global rss=enabled`

Comment: Coming back to this: one other thing I discovered is that, if your Samba server is behind a port forward (e.g. if you're running in a container on a hypervisor and you want Samba to appear to be hosted by the hypervisor), multichannel only works if the client can access the Samba server by its native container's IP ... meaning without the port forward. In my case, this meant adding a persistent IP route through the hypervisor host to the container with `route -p add (container subnet) (mask) (hypervisor host)`.

I couldn't figure out a way around this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Besides all the above useful information, I would add one more:

Enable **Jumbo Packet* under network adapter advanced settings - in my example 'Intel Ethernet Controller X540-AT2', using Windows 10.

Here's a screenshot:
[image: Advanced network adapter settings]